# Service starting failed - Failed to start SYSV

Tags: bash, python, services, init.d

My objective is to start a personal daemon called `gobatch`. `gobatch` is stored into `/usr/bin/gobatch`.

`gobatch` is a deamon that allows you to run cyclicaly at a date or a specific time a program. `gobatch` is write with Python. But during the test it is just an infinite loop.

When I use `/etc/init.d/gobatch start` I got this error :

> janv. 08 14:39:03 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: ChilliSpot is an open source captive portal.

**/usr/sbin/gobatch**

```
#! /bin/bash

while true;
do

done
```

**/etc/init.d/gobatch**

```
#!/bin/sh
#### BEGIN INIT INFO 
# Provides:          chillispot et freeradius dans le chroot 
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network 
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs _
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5 
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6 
# Short-Description: Wireless & LAN Access Point Controller 
# Description:       ChilliSpot is an open source captive portal 
#                    or wireless LAN access point controller. 
### END INIT INFO 


PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin 
DESC="Deamon that allows you to run cyclicaly at a date or a specific time a program" 
NAME=gobatch 
DEAMON=/usr/sbin/gobatch 
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid 
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/"$NAME" 

. /lib/lsb/init-functions 

case "$1" in 
start) log_daemon_msg "Starting gobatch" 
       start_daemon -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON 
       log_end_msg $? 
       ;; 
stop) log_daemon_msg "Stopping gobatch" 
      killproc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON 
      RETVAL=$? 
      [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && [ -e "$PIDFILE" ] && rm -f $PIDFILE 
      log_end_msg $RETVAL 
      ;; 
restart) log_daemon_msg "Restarting gobatch" 
         $0 stop 
         $0 start 
         ;; 
esac 
exit 0
```

Can you help me to fix this problem?

Thank's a lot!

**UPDATE**

It is possible than the problem is that I'm using `start_daemon -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON` and that my gobatch file is not a daemon but a bash script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154905/service-starting-failed-failed-to-start-sysv